# definitive list of colors by shade with hex values

Tags: colors, hexadecimal

I am looking for documentation on color.  I need to know the hex values for a list of common named colors, and what hue they belong to.  I would also like to know what the cutoff points are (in hex) between different hues.  For example At which point does a light blue become just  blue?  Now I know technically each color has exactly one value, but I am looking for ranges of approximate color.

Also, please note I am colorblind.  So when I look at a page that says the color is 'Myrtle'  I have no idea if that color is red, brown, orange, or green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_colornames.asp) has the most comprehensive list of hex color values and associated names that I have found, but I don't think the names are 'official'.

For your use, it's probably better sorted by hex value [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_colorvalues.asp).

Each color has a link to a page that defines the [shade values](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp?colorhex=00BFFF) too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how definitive this information from Microsoft is, but I found these two pages very useful.

[Color Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
[Dynamic Color Reference](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/colors/ColorTable.htm)

The first reference includes links in the left sidebar to other tables of colors sorted by hue, lightness and saturation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the sites that has helped me a lot with colors is http://www.colorcombos.com/.
Maybe it can help. I will try to find more sites and update here.